# how to create really smooth web animations for mobile?

Tags: javascript, animation, mobile

I would like to create some animations on my website that are smooth and seamless, especially on mobile devices. I have tried using various methods such as setInterval, requestAnimationFrame, the jQuery .animate() method, and the vanilla JS .animate() method. However, all of these methods seem to produce a twitchy effect on mobile devices, which is not what I want. Can you please suggest some techniques or libraries that would allow me to create truly smooth animations?

Here is an example of the kind of animation I would like.

```
let modal = document.getElementById('modal');
modal.animate(
    { 
        transform: [`translateX(${$('body').css('width')})`, $('#modal').css('left', '0px')],
        easing: 'ease-in-out'
    }, {
        duration: 500
    }
);
```